# Password auth failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to run my postgres server and nestjs project with docker script and it does fire up the server and database. While firing up it does run migrations too but when I open pgAdmin I see no database there and if i try to create new server i get fatal pasword incorrect error. Also my server crashes too with error saying `Password authentication failed for user "postgres"`. It was running fine yesterday but today its not running at all. I tried pruning everything and made fresh build and then compose up but nothing. Here is docker script

```
version: "3.5"
services:
    dev-api:
        container_name: xxxxxxxx-api
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        depends_on:
          - dev-db
        environment:
          DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgres:postgres@dev-db:5432/xxxxxxx_api
          APP_ENV: development
          PORT: 3030
          WAIT_HOSTS: dev-db:5432
        ports:
          - "3030:3030"
          - "9229:9229"
        volumes:
          - .:/usr/api/
    dev-db:
      container_name: xxxxxxxx-postgres
      image: postgres:13.5-alpine
      restart: always
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
      volumes:
        - ./pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        - ./src/db/docker/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dbinit.sql
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        - POSTGRES_DB=xxxxxxx_api
      expose:
        - "5432"
    pgadmin:
      container_name: xxxxxxx-pgadmin
      image: dpage/pgadmin4:6.2
      ports:
        - 8080:80
      volumes:
        - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
      environment:
        - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=user@postgres.com
        - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=postgres
        - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=80
      depends_on:
        - dev-db
volumes:
  pgadmin-data:
```

Comment: Be aware that if you have an existing database, then your POSTGRES_* variables aren't used for anything. They're only used if the container can't find an existing database and needs to create a new one. To make sure that you're starting from scratch, you could try removing the pg-data volume mapping.

Comment: Also, if your host machine is reachable from the internet, then it's possible that you have an intruder, since your postgres container has a username and password that's very easy to guess.

Comment: @HansKilian this is just test data for now and all will be changed. However I've just tried by removing all volumes and containers now but still same error